# array not working mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to create an array from an mysql query,
It gets around 300 values from the database yet only the first value is stored in the array. when I echo the array it says: Array ( [0] => 0.99 ). What I'm trying to archieve is 
Array ( [0] => 0.99 ) 
 
Array ( [1] => 0.25 ) 
etc.

```
$activering = mysql_query("SELECT tarieven.id, bundels.bundel_id, betaalmethodes.bet_id , bundels.psp_id, bundels.aanmeldkosten, bundels.maandelijkse_kosten, bundels.transactiekosten, bundels.batchkosten, psp.psp_naam,  tarieven.percentage, tarieven.prijs, bundels.actief 
FROM tarieven
INNER JOIN bundels
ON tarieven.bundel_id = bundels.bundel_id
INNER JOIN betaalmethodes
ON tarieven.bet_id = betaalmethodes.bet_id
INNER JOIN psp
ON bundels.psp_id = psp.psp_id");
    if($activering === FALSE) { die(mysql_error()); } // to do better error handling
        if ($result = mysql_fetch_array($activering)) {
            $prijs =                array($result['prijs']); }
```

It's probably something really easy but I just don't see it..

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($activering)) {
    $prijs[] = array($result['prijs']); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your over writing the value(array) in hte loop so you only get the last one:

```
   $prijs[] =$result['prijs']; }
```

Comment: Array ( [0] => 0.99 ) Still only this output